insert an associative array into the Yii2 migration
There are 4 tables in the database: months, types, prices, tonnages
There is an array of the following type:
'prices'=> [
        'soy' => [
          'january' => [
                50 => 145,
                75 => 136,
                100 => 138
            ],
           'february' => [
                50 => 100,
                75 => 125,
                100 => 108
            ],
            ....
          ],
        'hay' => 
            'january' => [
                50 => 105,
                75 => 116,
                100 => 118
            ],
           'february' => [
                50 => 100,
                75 => 125,
                100 => 108
            ],
        ....

This array is an example of data that should be loaded into a database by migrating to a table named prices.
The prices table has the same fields as: month_id, tonnage_id, type_id, price.
The months, types, and tonnages tables are filled in. How can I compare the data and upload it to the database?
I have a code that already works, but it seems to me that it turned out to be unnecessarily complicated.
public function safeUp()
{
   $months = $this->getDb()->createCommand('SELECT * FROM months')->queryAll();
   $tonnages = $this->getDb()->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tonnages')->queryAll();
   $types = $this->getDb()->createCommand('SELECT * FROM raw_types')->queryAll();
   $columns = ['price', 'month_id', 'tonnage_id', 'type_id'];
   $rows =  MigrationHelper::toRecords(Yii::$app->params['prices'], $months, $tonnages, $types);
   $this->batchInsert('prices', $columns, $rows);
}

public static function toRecords(array $arr, array $months, array $tonnages, array $types): array
{
  $result = [];
  foreach ($arr as $type => $typeValues) {
     $typeId = self::findIdByField($types, 'name', $type);
     foreach ($typesValues as $month => $monthValue) {
        $monthId = self::findIdByField($types, 'name', $month);
         foreach ($monthValues as $tonnage => $price) {
           $tonnageId = self::findIdByField($types, 'value', $tonnag);
           $result[] = [
              'price' = $price,
              'month_id' => $monthId,
              'tonnage_id' => $tonnageId,
              'type_id' => $typeId
          ];
         }
      }
  }
  return $result;
}

private static function findIdByField(array $arr, string $fieldName, int | string $value) : int 
{
  foreach ($arr as $item) {
   if ($item[$fieldName] === $value) {
      return $item['id'];
   }
  }
}


I don't understand the question. How is the array that you show related to the $result array being created in the function?

this array is passed as a function parameter
$rows =  MigrationHelper::toRecords(Yii::$app->params['prices'], $months, $tonnages, $types);
Yii::$app->params['prices'] = there is a described array

What's wrong with the code as you have it? If you want to process all the data, you need nested loops like that.

@Barmar It seems to me that the problem may be with a large amount of data. At the moment, the array contains few records, but won't it affect performance if the array contains a large amount of data?

I'm going to assume queryAll() simply returns an array of associative arrays. You should convert them to associative arrays keyed off the fields you want to search, rather than using findIdByField(), which is presumably a linear search.
public static function toRecords(array $arr, array $months, array $tonnages, array $types): array
{
    $result = [];
    $types = array_combine(array_column($types, 'name'), array_column($types, 'id'));
    $months = array_combine(array_column($months, 'name'), array_column($months, 'id'));
    $tonnages = array_combine(array_column($tonnage, 'value'), array_column($tonnage, 'id'));

    foreach ($arr as $type => $typeValues) {
        $typeId = $types[$type];
        foreach ($typesValues as $month => $monthValue) {
            $monthId = $months[$month]
            foreach ($monthValues as $tonnage => $price) {
                $tonnageId = $tonnages[$tonnage];
                $result[] = [
                    'price' = $price,
                    'month_id' => $monthId,
                    'tonnage_id' => $tonnageId,
                    'type_id' => $typeId
                ];
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}


Well, you're damn right. This saved me from an unnecessary function and surprisingly the migration began to happen a little faster than it used to be.

What to do when someone answers your question
